# Comparing two data.frames and deleting rows based on NA values in one data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One is considered a reference and has every value, the other may or may not be missing values. I want to compare both data frames, then delete the values from the reference data frame that have NA in the other. However, each row of the data frame that can have missing values needs to be treated as a single comparison so you are developing a unique reference for every single row. For example the reference dataframe(1):

```
  var1   var2   var3
1   a      b      c
2   q      w      e
3   z      x      n
```

The other data frame(2):

```
   var1    var2    var3
1    p       o       i
2    u       y       t
3    NA      e       w
4    l       k       NA
```

For row 1 and 2 of data frame 2 I need a full reference since no missing values:

```
  var1   var2   var3
1   a      b      c
2   q      w      e
3   z      x      n
```

For row 3 of data frame 2 I need:

```
    var2   var3
1    b      c
2    w      e
3    x      n
```

For row 4 of data frame 2 I need:

```
  var1   var2   
1   a      b      
2   q      w      
3   z      x
```

Comment: The expected output is confusing.  Can you show the dataframe2 after the change

Comment: dataframe 2 never changes. It is used to define variables for a new dataframe based on the values of dataframe 1.

Comment: If you look at the letters of the last 3 dataframes that are created you will see their values come from dataframe 1. If there is an NA in dataframe 2, that variable is removed in the new dataframe with dataframe 1 values for that variable removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
> ref<-data.frame(var1=c('a','q','z'),var2=c('b','w','x'),var3=c('c','e','n'))
> new<-data.frame(var1=c('p','u',NA,'l'),var2=c('o','y','e','k'),var3=c('i','t','w',NA))
> apply(new,1,function(x) ref[,which(!is.na(x))] )
[[1]]
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    b    c
2    q    w    e
3    z    x    n

[[2]]
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    b    c
2    q    w    e
3    z    x    n

[[3]]
  var2 var3
1    b    c
2    w    e
3    x    n

[[4]]
  var1 var2
1    a    b
2    q    w
3    z    x
```

As requested in author's comment, if he also wants to:

> "remove +1 index if the NA is at an odd index, and -1 index if the NA is at an even index".

```
is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 == 1
apply(new, 1, function(x) {
    toremove <-which(is.na(x))
    toremove1<-sapply(toremove,function(x) ifelse(is.odd(x),x+1,x-1) )
    ref[,!(1:ncol(ref) %in% c(toremove,toremove1)),drop=F]
})
```

Comment: That works. I have one more curveball for that though. What if for the new dataframe each variable is associated with the variable next to it. For example if var 1 has an NA value then you remove var 1 and var 2. If var 3 has an NA value you remove var 3 and var 4, etc. Every two variables is associated.

Comment: then use: `apply(new,1,function(x) {toremove=c(which(is.na(x)),which(is.na(x))+1); ref[,!(1:ncol(ref) %in% toremove),drop=F] })`

Comment: so I am slightly modifying your code but I've run into a snag. I am trying to remove +1 index if the NA is at an odd index, and -1 index if the NA is at an even index. I think my code works, it's just an issue of when there is no TRUE/FALSE return. Care to take a look?

is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 == 1 #creates odd/even check

apply(new, 1, function(x) { 

if(is.odd(which(is.na(x)))) { toremove=c(which(is.na(x)), which(is.na(x))+1) }

if(!is.odd(which(is.na(x)))) { toremove=c(which(is.na(x)), which(is.na(x))-1)}

ref[,!(1:ncol(ref) %in% toremove),drop=F]
})