# Attempting to create new dataframes using a reference dataframe based on NA values from another

Tags: r

This is a bit odd to explain. I have two dataframes. The first is a reference, the second may or may not have missing values. Both dataframes share the same variables. If there is an NA in the second dataframe I want to create a new dataframe based on the reference values but remove that variable that's missing. Each odd and even variables are associated. So if an odd variable has an NA value, that variable + the next variable needs to be removed in the new dataframe. If there is an even variable with an NA value that variable + the previous variable needs to be removed. So var 1 and var 2 are related, var 3 and var 4, var 5 and var 6, etc. More or less I have it working, but my code is having issues with NULL values.

```
is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 == 1
apply(new, 1, function(x) {

    if(is.odd(which(is.na(x)))) {
        toremove=c(which(is.na(x)), which(is.na(x))+1)
    }

    if(!is.odd(which(is.na(x)))) {
        toremove=c(which(is.na(x)), which(is.na(x))-1)
    }

    ref[,!(1:ncol(ref) %in% toremove), drop=F]
})
```

The error I am getting is "Error in if (is.odd(which(is.na(x)))) { : argument is a length of zero".

Here is an example of what I want. The first is the reference dataframe:

```
    var1    var2    var3    var4
1    q        w      e        r
2    t        y      u        i
3    o        p      a        s
4    d        f      g        h
```

The second has missing NA values:

```
    var1    var2    var3    var4
1    1        1      1        1
2    1        3      2        NA
3    1        NA     a        s
4    d        f      g        h
```

Each row of the second dataframe is used to create the new dataframe based on reference values. For the first row the output should be complete since there are no NAs:

```
    var1    var2    var3    var4
1    q        w      e        r
2    t        y      u        i
3    o        p      a        s
4    d        f      g        h
```

For the second row the output should be missing the 3rd and 4th variable since the 4th had an NA and 3 + 4 (odd + even) are related. :

```
    var1    var2    
1    q        w      
2    t        y      
3    o        p     
4    d        f
```

Update: I think the problem is with which(is.na(x) returning numeric(0). I'm attempting to control for that with:

```
if(!identical(which(is.na(x))), numeric(0)) {}
```

But it doesn't appear to be matching.

Comment: You should at least link to your previous post since I answered the question there and let me know you were starting a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537091/comparing-two-data-frames-and-deleting-rows-based-on-na-values-in-one-data-frame

Comment: @fishtank sorry for not linking the previous post. Your answer there ended up being the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
 apply(df2, 1, function(x) {if(all(!is.na(x))) 
                       df1 else {
                          i1 <- which(is.na(x))
                      df1[-c(sapply(i1, function(i) 
                       if(!i%%2) c(max(1, i-1), i)
                        else c(i, min(length(x), i+1))))]
                              }
                              }
                              )

#$`1`
#  var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    q    w    e    r
#2    t    y    u    i
#3    o    p    a    s
#4    d    f    g    h

#$`2`
#  var1 var2
#1    q    w
#2    t    y
#3    o    p
#4    d    f

#$`3`
#  var3 var4
#1    e    r
#2    u    i
#3    a    s
#4    g    h

#$`4`
#  var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    q    w    e    r
#2    t    y    u    i
#3    o    p    a    s
#4    d    f    g    h
```